# Prove that the sequence is strictly increasing

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that if $(a_n)$ and $(c_n)$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) are strictly increasing positive integer sequences with $a_n^2 \mid c_n^2+1$, then the 
>   sequence defined by $b_n = c_n+a_n^2c_n-a_n^3$ is strictly increasing.

This result holds if $c_n-a_n$ is increasing since $c_n+a_n^2c_n-a_n^3 = c_n+a_n^2(c_n-a_n)$. What if it isn't?

Comment: still false with $a_1 = 100, a_2 = 200, c_1 = 200, c_2 = 201$

Comment: Just an observation, $a_n^2 | c_n^2 + 1$ is equivalent to the [negative Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation) $c_n^2 - k a_n^2 = -1$. This drastically limits the range of possible values $a_n, c_n$ and may help with the proof (though I don't see it offhand).

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false.

If $a_1=1, a_2=3, c_1=1, c_2=2$, we have $b_1=1$ and $b_2=-7$.

Comment: I changed the question.